# Automatically break span and keep right aligned

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a `label` and a `span` inside a `div` where the content of the `span` is dynamic.
The label should always be right aligned and if there's not enough space for its content in the line it should automatically break to the next line and keep it alignment at the right side.

**Initial situation:**
[image]

**After the content of the `span` changes:**
[image]

**How it should look like:**
[image]

Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/hj9zstjc/1/

Is there a solution for this?

I've already tried doing this with `flexbox` which allowed me to right align the value `span` and to automatically wrap it to the the next line when needed but i wasn't able to figure out how to keep the right alignment after the line break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
span
{
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
}
```

And for wrapper clearfix

```
.wrapper 
{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/The_Freedom/hj9zstjc/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Flexbox**

```js
var input = $('input');
input.on('input', function() {
 $('span.value').text(input.val() + "€");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 130px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

label {
  flex: 1;
}

span.value {
  margin-left: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="200">
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Gesamtpreis:</label>
  <span class="value">200 €</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Deepak Yadav Thanks, i think i fixed it.

Comment: it still don't see it working, the label and values are overlapping. I added a css fix, hope this is what he wants

Answer (score 0):

This should be your solution:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 130px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

span.value {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

Also look here: https://jsfiddle.net/0g8e081f/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can always do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/hj9zstjc/4/

Added an

```
overflow:auto;
```

on your .wrapper and an

```
float:right;
```

on your span.